# Java Spring Boot - how to enable user to switch data files from command line?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm using a JSON file with thousands of rows (that serves as a "database"). It is being deserialized and then the logic of the app is based on deserialized pojos.

I'd like to enable user to switch these JSON files before running the app in the command line: (e.g.)

```
 java -jar target/app.jar -source=resources/data.json
```

The app is built with Spring Boot and I've been reading files like that:

```
file = ResourceUtils.getFile("/Users/App/src/main/resources/data.json");
```

I've found some instructions about loading properties, but what i would like to do is to load a whole file and I can't seem to find a reliable instruction.

Edit:

application.properties:

```
source = filepath
```

fragment of my DAO:

```
  @Repository
  public class SomethingDao {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    private File file;

    @Value("${source}")
    private String source;

    {
        try {
            file = ResourceUtils.getFile(source);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            something = mapper.readValue(file, Something.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

commands i tried to use:

```
java -jar target/app.jar -source="src/main/resources/data.json"
java -jar target/app.jar -source="/data.json"
java -jar target/app.jar --source="src/main/resources/data.json"
java -jar target/app.jar --source="/data.json"
and so on...
```

Comment: Are you asking how to load a file, or are you asking how to get command-line arguments? Please do some **research**, e.g. a web search for [`spring boot command line arguments`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+command+line+arguments) would yield some of the duplicate link above.

Answer (score 1):

Achieve this by using `application.properties` or `application.yml`, specify the property in `application.properties` and override it through command line [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

**application.properties**

```
source = filepath
```

In **Service** or **Business** class

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

     @Value("${source}")
     private String name;

     public void someMethod() {

       file = ResourceUtils.getFile(source);
     }

  }
```

**Command**

```
java -jar target/app.jar -source="src/main/resources/data.json"
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer.
I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null" while trying to run the app. I've tried with -source and --source but neither seems to be working. Also my IDE tells me "Cannot resolve configuration property" pointing to the "source = filepath". Could You please help me with this?

Comment: Have you declared that property in application.properties

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the whole concept of this. Am I supposed to put a specific filepath in application.properties? Like "source="src/main/resources/data.json"? Or just type the "source=filepath"? Neither works anyway. I thought I'll be able to choose the file, so the first option makes no sense.

Comment: Can you update the code

Comment: Updated in edit

Comment: If you can, please upload the code to git and share the link, i can't overthink with this bit of code

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I can't send You the code though. I've ended up doing it the 'static' way like so "ClassPathResource("data.json").getInputStream();".
It can't be changed through the command line, but the data is loaded from resources folder.